# Expected name at xx:yy in JSON file in eclipse

Tags: json

```
"LOTGraphData": [
    {
        buildUnits:"1"
        ScheduledUnits:2"
        prodGroupId:"9288"
    },
    {
        buildUnits:"1"
        ScheduledUnits:2"
        prodGroupId:"9289"
    },
    {
        buildUnits:"1"
        ScheduledUnits:2"
        prodGroupId:"9280"
    }
    ]
}
```

This is the end of JSON file.

Comment: It shows expected name at LOTGraphData": [ { buildUnits:"1" S

Comment: You don't have the keys/value pairs in your object separated by commas. For example, `{buildUnits:"1" ScheduledUnits:2" prodGroupId:"9288"}` should probably be `{ buildUnits:"1", ScheduledUnits:2", prodGroupId:"9288" }`. And I'm not sure, but key times like `buildUnits` and  `ScheduledUnits` might have to be in quotes

Comment: @bwalshy Thanks, it worked and I have to put the keys in double quotes

Comment: Cool, since it worked I'll put it as an answer so the question doesn't appear unsolved

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your key/value pairs by commas. And (as per your confirmation), the keys have to be wrapped in quotes. So the final result will look like:

```
"LOTGraphData": [
    {
        "buildUnits": "1",
        "ScheduledUnits": "2",
        "prodGroupId": "9288"
    },
    {
        "buildUnits": "1",
        "ScheduledUnits": "2",
        "prodGroupId": "9289"
    },
    {
        "buildUnits": "1",
        "ScheduledUnits": "2",
        "prodGroupId": "9280"
    }
]
```